# xml xslt: how to concatenate two fields in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have input xml as

```
<FileDetailRecord>
<Detail number="1">
<API>Test_API</API>
<RESOURCEPATH>/abc/{gamezone}</RESOURCEPATH>
</Detail>
<Detail number="2">
<API>Test_API</API>
<RESOURCEPATH>/gamehub</RESOURCEPATH>
</Detail>
</FileDetailRecord>
```

I need to convert this to

```
<FileDetailRecord>
<Detail number="1">
<API>TestAPI_/abc/{gamezone}</API>
</Detail>
<Detail number="2">
<API>TestAPI_/gamehub</API>
</Detail>
</FileDetailRecord>
```

I have tried many ways to concate using following way:

```
<xsl:template match="API">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(API,'-',RESOURCEPATH)" />
</xsl:template>
```

But this does not seems to be working. Can some one please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `Test_API` is converted to `Telenor_API`?

Comment: no that should be Test_API only in output xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

First use identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

remove `RESOURCEPATH` with

```
<xsl:template match="RESOURCEPATH"/>
```

Then move `RESOURCEPATH` in `API` with

```
<xsl:template match="API">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Telenor_API_' , following-sibling::RESOURCEPATH)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

See transform at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzV/1

If you want to retain `<API>` value than see transform on https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzV